# Magento 2 - Disable product attribute if custom module is disabled

Tags: magento-2.1

I have created few product attributes in custom module using UpgradeData.

Now if I disable my module then I how can I disable the product attributes as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that automatically.
Actually, you cannot disable attributes at all.
But you can have and `Uninstall.php` similar to `UpgradeData.php` that is called when the module is uninstalled (not disabled).
You can put a cleanup script in there. 
But it only works if your module is installed via composer.
More details in the [official documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-uninstall-mods.html#instgde-cli-uninst-mod-uninst)